# not able to redirect to jsp spring mvc-No xml configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring 4.2.2 hence using no xml configuration
**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.hyundai</groupId>
  <artifactId>carworkshop</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>carworkshop Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jackson.version>2.6.3</jackson.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.3</logback.version>
        <jcl.slf4j.version>1.7.12</jcl.slf4j.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <servletapi.version>3.1.0</servletapi.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.2.0.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Need this for json to/from object -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL for views -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jcl.slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- compile only, deployed container will provide this -->
        <!-- Need this for config annotation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servletapi.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibe dependencies added by dev team -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Added for spring transaction  -->
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>



            <plugin> 
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**AppInitializer class**

```
package com.hyundai.initilaizer;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

import com.hyundai.config.AppWebConfig;



public class AppInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppWebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

**AppWebConfig class**

```
package com.hyundai.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.hyundai.web" })
public class AppWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

**Welcome.jsp**

```
<%@page session="false"%>
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Spring MVC 4 + Ajax Hello World</title>

<c:url var="home" value="/" scope="request" />

<spring:url value="/resources/core/css/hello.css" var="coreCss" />
<spring:url value="/resources/core/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    var="bootstrapCss" />
<link href="${bootstrapCss}" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="${coreCss}" rel="stylesheet" />

<spring:url value="/resources/core/js/jquery.1.10.2.min.js"
    var="jqueryJs" />
<script src="${jqueryJs}"></script>
</head>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CarWorkshop</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container" style="min-height: 500px">

    <div class="starter-template">
        <h1>Search Form</h1>
        <br>

        <div id="feedback"></div>

        <form class="form-horizontal" id="search-form">
            <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">VehicleRegNo</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type=text class="form-control" id="vehicleRegNo">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">JobDate</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="jobDate">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" id="bth-search"
                        class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="container">
    <footer>
        <p>
            &copy; <a href="http://www.tcs.com">Mkyong.com</a> 2015
        </p>
    </footer>
</div>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $("#search-form").submit(function(event) {

            // Disble the search button
            enableSearchButton(false);

            // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser.
            event.preventDefault();

            searchViaAjax();

        });

    });

    function searchViaAjax() {

        var search = {}
        search["vehicleRegNo"] = $("#vehicleRegNo").val();
        search["jobDate"] = $("#jobDate").val();

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            contentType : "application/json",
            url : "${home}search/api/getSearchResult",
            data : JSON.stringify(search),
            dataType : 'json',
            timeout : 100000,
            success : function(data) {
                console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
                display(data);
            },
            error : function(e) {
                console.log("ERROR: ", e);
                display(e);
            },
            done : function(e) {
                console.log("DONE");
                enableSearchButton(true);
            }
        });

    }

    function enableSearchButton(flag) {
        $("#btn-search").prop("disabled", flag);
    }

    function display(data) {
        var json = "<h4>Ajax Response</h4><pre>"
                + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4) + "</pre>";
        $('#feedback').html(json);
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**AjaxController.java**

```
package com.hyundai.web.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;
import com.hyundai.web.entity.AjaxResponseBody;
import com.hyundai.web.entity.Employee;
import com.hyundai.web.entity.Job;
import com.hyundai.web.entity.Jobline;
import com.hyundai.web.entity.SearchCriteria;
import com.hyundai.web.entity.Task;
import com.hyundai.web.jsonview.Views;

@RestController
public class AjaxController {

    List<Job> jobs;

    // @ResponseBody, not necessary, since class is annotated with @RestController
    // @RequestBody - Convert the json data into object (SearchCriteria) mapped by field name.
    // @JsonView(Views.Public.class) - Optional, limited the json data display to client.
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search/api/getSearchResult")
    public AjaxResponseBody getSearchResultViaAjax(@RequestBody SearchCriteria search) {

        AjaxResponseBody result = new AjaxResponseBody();

        if (isValidSearchCriteria(search)) {
            List<Job> jobs = findByVehRegOrJobDt(search.getVehRegNo(), search.getJobDate());

            if (jobs.size() > 0) {
                result.setCode("200");
                result.setMsg("");
                result.setResult(jobs);
            } else {
                result.setCode("204");
                result.setMsg("No jobs!");
            }

        } else {
            result.setCode("400");
            result.setMsg("Search criteria is empty!");
        }

        //AjaxResponseBody will be converted into json format and send back to client.
        return result;

    }

    private boolean isValidSearchCriteria(SearchCriteria search) {

        boolean valid = true;

        if (search == null) {
            valid = false;
        }

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(search.getVehRegNo())){
            valid = false;
        }

        return valid;
    }

    // Init some users for testing
    @PostConstruct
    private void iniDataForTesting() {

        Task task1 =new Task();
        task1.setTaskName("painting");

        Task task2 =new Task();
        task2.setTaskName("mechanical");

        Jobline jobline1 = new Jobline();
        jobline1.setId(1);
        jobline1.setTask(task1);

        Jobline jobline2 = new Jobline();
        jobline2.setId(2);
        jobline2.setTask(task2);

        Set<Jobline> jobLineSet = new HashSet<Jobline>();
        jobLineSet.add(jobline1);
        jobLineSet.add(jobline2);


        Employee emp1 = new Employee();
        emp1.setEmpName("John");


        Job job1 =new Job(1, emp1, "or02av7434", new Date(),
                jobLineSet);

        Job job2 =new Job(2, emp1, "or02bz9000", new Date(),
                jobLineSet);

        Job job3 =new Job(3, emp1, "or02bk5630", new Date(),
                jobLineSet);



        jobs = new ArrayList<Job>();
        jobs.add(job1);
        jobs.add(job2);
        jobs.add(job3);

    }

    // Simulate the search function
    private List<Job> findByVehRegOrJobDt(String vehRegno, String providedDate) {

        List<Job> result = new ArrayList<Job>();

        for (Job job : jobs) {

            if ((!StringUtils.isEmpty(vehRegno)) && (!StringUtils.isEmpty(vehRegno))) {

                if (vehRegno.equals(job.getVehRegNo()) && providedDate.equals(job.getJobDate())) {
                    result.add(job);
                    continue;
                } else {
                    continue;
                }

            }
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(vehRegno)) {
                if (vehRegno.equals(job.getVehRegNo())) {
                    result.add(job);
                    continue;
                }
            }


        }

        return result;

    }
}
```

when I deploy the above project and hitting http://localhost:8080/carworkshop. It is not taking me to welcome.jsp. Please help me where I am going wrong. Basically I want to write a simple application with spring mvc 4.2.2, ajax and jquery. where I will be redirected from root context to welcome.jsp, page and I will do some basic search operation

Answer (score 1):

It's like you are missing view controller. You are trying to resolve view using Servlets. I'm not sure if that's right approach..

In Spring mvc is done with @Controller annotation and @RequestMapping, 
ie:

```
@Controller
public class WebController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/")
  public String signin() {
    return "signin";  //directs to your /WEB-INF/views/jsp/signin.jsp
  }
}
```

[this](https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype) github project serves as a good and quick spring reference project

Answer (score 0):

You have provided a RestController for handling your JSON endpoint requests, but you will also need a @Controller (note not @RestController) for handling the serving of your welcome JSP.

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController { 

  @RequestMapping(value = "/")
  public String welcome() {
    return "Welcome"; //will resolve to /WEB-INF/views/jsp/Welcome.jsp
  }
}
```

Whenever you want to serve up rendered JSP content, you should have an MVC controller defined to handle those requests.

Comment: Already have that in my code
package com.hyundai.web.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

 @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
  return "welcome";
 }

}

Comment: You are trying to access /carworkshop. Is that supposed to be the context root of the application, or the actual URL mapping you want to have your welcome.jsp returned at? If its the context root, where do you have that defined in the configuration? If you want /carworkshop to return the welcome.jsp, you will need to change your request mapping to `@RequestMapping(value = "/carworkshop")`

Comment: where to define the context root in configuration??

Comment: In your `AppInitializer` class you should be able to change the pattern from "/" to "/carworkshop". However, the context root can also be inferred by the deployment name of your artifact. For example, if the artifact you are deploying is called `workshop.war`, your application should be available at `localhost:8080/workshop/`

Comment: and do you get anything returned when you access localhost:8080/workshop/ while the application workshop.war is deployed and running?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109277/discussion-between-gladiator-9-and-alexanderific).